# Is there a way to change the geolocation of the request in requests_html?

Tags: python, xpath, request, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrape some Facebook post stats (number of reactions, comments, views or shares) with requests_html package. I used this approach because I had to render the initial page source since Facebook uses some lazy loading scripts.

I managed to do it but it depends on the geolocation. For example, if I make the request from my local machine the comment count span will be in my country's language, but if I use a UK VPN it will be displayed in English (E.g. '5 comments').

The goal is to deploy the code into cloud and to standardize it to a single Language to be more robust.

I tried sending the Accept-Language header as shown in the snippet below, but no success.
Please note that the xpath might change if the page structure changes.

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8',
    'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
}

r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
r.html.render(timeout=10, wait=2, sleep=2)

xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/div/span'

comments = r.html.xpath(xpath, first=True).text
```

Thank you in advance!